# Delete Element in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I try to delete an element in Xml but currently im just removing the "sub-element"
XML:

```
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install">
</dependentAssembly>
```

Current Code:

```
string filePath = "C:\\Example\\Example.exe.manifest"
var xml = XElement.Load(filePath);
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Remove();
xml.Save(filePath);
```

Xml after Code:

```
<dependency>
 <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
 </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
</dependency>
```

As you see im currently just deleting `<dependentAssembly>` but i try to delete `<dependency>`

How shall i do That?

i never did that much in XML so i try to learn from you guys :)

Comment: This is the third (at least) question you've asked about this problem, and you're *still* not posting representative XML - you haven't included any of the namespaces involved, despite multiple requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options. You could select the parent node to remove:

```
xml.Descendants()
   .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && 
               (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
   .Select(x => x.Parent)
   .Remove();
```

Or you could use `Any` to find elements with any such child:

```
xml.Descendants()
   .Where(p => p.Elements()
                .Any(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && 
                          (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")))
   .Remove();
```

I would also strongly recommend *not* matching by `LocalName`, but instead working out the full namespace-qualified element name you want, e.g.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://somenamespace";
xml.Descendants(ns + "dependency")
   .Where(p => p.Elements(ns + "dependentAssembly")
                .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")))
   .Remove();
```

Comment: Jon Skeet you always help me out Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

With your current statement you are just selecting the nodes that are dependentAssembly and have the dependency attribute set to install. What you want is the parent node containing such a node. Therefore I suggest to modify your statement to:

```
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();
```

I hope that solves your problem.